# Does the lamellar structure in say a copper-silver phase diagram have any unique mechanical properties?

Tags: materials, mechanical-properties

For example, at lower amounts of silver the alloy gets stronger due to precipitation hardening, so in the composition as the wt% of silver increases how do the mechanical properties change? Both of them are FCC structure, so does the ductility remain the same as well?

Comment: If there is precipitate hardening, what happens to the ductility?

Comment: Oh, by both of them I was referring to the silver and copper respectively, not for lower amounts. Is there any precipitate hardening in a lamellar structure? I am trying to compare the mechanical properties of say 2% and the a alloy with a eutectic composition (Although now that you mention it I assume the lower amount would also have potentially lower ductility)